# Is there a way to convert RGB images to specific text values?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create a 2D Colour Barcode Encoder and Decoder. For a given input text, a coloured barcode is generated and conversely, when an RGB image is uploaded, it is decoded into the text. I have done the encoding part but finding difficulties in decoding it.
On clicking the "Upload" button, we can upload an RGB image. Now, this image needs to be decoded into a text that appears in the textbox.
Letters A, B, C and D respectively for red, green, yellow and blue colours.

[Image encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQO3k.png)

**Code for encoding:**

```
function encode_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
inputstring=get(handles.inp,'string'); %take input
letters='ABCD';   %initialise the letters to be used
lettercolours=uint8([255,0,0;  ... for A
                 0,255,0; ...for B
                 255,255,0; ... for C 
                 0,0,255]); % for D   
[found, whichrow] = ismember(inputstring, letters); %find which colour goes with each letter of the input
assert(all(found), 'Some letters in input are not valid');
letterswidth = diff(round(linspace(0, 1024, numel(inputstring)+1)));    %compute width of each letter colour patch.
colouredimage = repelem(permute(lettercolours(whichrow, :), [3 1 2]), 1024, letterswidth, 1);   %replicate each colour patch according to calculate width and a 1024 height. 
imshow(colouredimage);
```

[image: Image Decoding]

**Code for decoding:**

```
function decode_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global img %using the global variable 'img' from the "upload" function
index=1;   %initialise index of 'text' variable to 1
for i=150:200:1024

red=img(500,i,1);   %extract value of 'R' at (500,i)
green=img(500,i,2); %extract value of 'G' at (500,i)
blue=img(500,i,3);  %extract value of 'B' at (500,i)
if(red==255&&green==0&&blue==0)
text(index)='A';   %store the letter 'A' in array 'text'
index=index+1;     %increment the index for next colour
set(handles.out,'string',text);
elseif(red==0&&green==255&&blue==0)
text(index)='B';   %store the letter 'B' in array 'text'
index=index+1;     %increment the index for next colour
set(handles.out,'string',text);
elseif(red==255&&green==255&&blue==0)
text(index)='C';   %store the letter 'C' in array 'text'
index=index+1;     %increment the index for next colour
set(handles.out,'string',text);
elseif(red==0&&green==0&&blue==255)
text(index)='D';  %store the letter 'D' in array 'text'
index=index+1;    %increment the index for next colour
set(handles.out,'string',text);
end
end
```

This is what I tried doing for decoding the image into text. I'm getting output as expected. The only thing I'm lacking in my code is to give automatic spacing between the colours. In my code, I have chosen a spacing of 200 pixels. This works well only if there are 5 columns (colours). If the no. of columns increase, their width will decrease and if the no. of columns decrease, their width will increase. So, the idea of increasing the x-coordinate by 200 will not work everytime. This is the only thing that remains to be done.

Comment: If you've already done the encoding, it seems that the decoding should be fairly straightforward. What *specifically* are you having trouble with?

Comment: Encoding was simpler. The problem with decoding is, how do I really convert the image into text. What method? I thought of using RGB extraction as one of the method. But I'm unable to write a code for it.

Comment: Do your input images follow a fixed format (i.e. N columns of a specific color per letter), or do you have to be able to process any arbitrary image? These details matter, and we can't help you much without them. Also, it would help to include the code you have so far for encoding and loading an image.

Comment: No, there's no fixed format. The no. of columns keep on changing depending upon the input given. Lesser the no. of input characters, broader will be each colour and vice-versa.
I have edited my question and added the code for encoding .

Comment: Can you have repeated letters? That could cause a problem, since `'AB'` would look the same as `'AABB'`.

Comment: Yes, repeated letters are allowed. Yes, they do look the same but we may use numel function to get the length of input text and divide the width of the image into equal parts. 
Eg: AABB will have length=4. So, we divide width (1024 pixels) into 4 equal parts each of 256. Now we can perform the necessary operations on each column. (1 to 256), (257 to 512), (513 to 768) and (769 to 1024)

Comment: I meant that it will cause a problem with your *decoding*, since the images will look the same and you will have no knowledge of the number of letters they were created with. For example, an image that is half red, half green could have been created with `'AB'` or `'AABB'`. You have to determine the number of letters when decoding, and certain situations will be ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, I got you. That's the special case. I'm just looking for some output at the moment. Close to the exact output is also okay as of now.

Comment: @NitinTiwari I'm confused as to what you're actually asking. In your question you state "The only thing I'm lacking in my code is to give automatic spacing between the colours," but in your comment above, you correctly state that you need to "divide width (1024 pixels) into 4 equal parts each of 256." What is it you need help with?

Comment: 4 equal parts was just an example in context to your 'AABB' thing which you mentioned.
Let's say my input image consists of Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Red colours in the sequence. Here, 5 columns (colours) exist. So it's 1024/5. If I add one more colour, let's say Blue again, the no. of columns now increase to 6. So, it's 1024/6 now. The change is dynamic. My question is how exactly can I write a code that will automatically generate equal spacing depending upon the no. of columns?

Comment: I guess that's my question. In the `AABB` example that @gnovice gave (not me), how do you know that there are 4 columns instead of 2? If you know somehow the number of columns represented in the image, say `k`, then you just need to divide the width of the image by `k`. Detecting the number of color bars in an image is trivial. Determining whether a single color bar encodes 1, 2, 3, or 30 characters is impossible (in certain cases) without outside information.

Comment: I have one idea in my mind. Since an image is a matrix of rows and columns (1024x1024 in this case). We can create a while loop that stores the RGB values starting from column=1 and running till column=1024. So while the RGB value is [255 0 0] i.e. red colour, display the text 'A'. Similarly, while RGB=[ 0 255 0] i.e. green colour, display the text 'B'. I'm not concerned about 'AB' and 'AABB' as of now. I'm just concerned about the right text for right colour.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking as a hard question, since yellow is red and green would it then represent A + B + C? Also whats the threshold on deciding if a colour is red or orange for example? I think there is a reason why QR codes for example are 1 colour. You can however design a barcode in the conventional way using spacings and line thickness and use it like that.

Sorry, the photo did not load the first time.
To get the RGB values. For example,
`img(183, 17, :)`
would extract the R, G, and B components (in that order) of row 183 column 17 of the image.

Comment: The triplet of RGB values in uint8 format. For red, it is [255 0 0]. For green, it is [255 255 0] and so on.
The expected output is ADBCD

Comment: Actually I have tried doing what you suggested. I'm actually looking for some algorithm/code that will help me converting them to text. 
The x-coordinate will keep changing from colour to colour. Example, I want the RGB values at (100,100), (300,100), (500,100) and so on.

Comment: I would suggest reading out the colour of the stripes one by one and between every read check which colour it is and store the letter that matches that colour. Repeat this progress 5 times and you should have the string. My matlab experience is to little to code out an example i'm sorry

Comment: It's okay, thanks for your help. Actually, this image is just an example. The solution won't work if I give some other text value as an input.